# Issue with "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, i386

We're having an android/ios app which was building ok up to this moment in Xcode. On monday we upgraded Xcode to Version 6.1.1. Since then I can't build and run our app in Xcode simulators.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ACCOUNTZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Accountz-crbaoextdggovrahxqcivilxfgeh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/ACCOUNTZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Accountz-crbaoextdggovrahxqcivilxfgeh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[CDVInAppBrowser openInSystem:] in CDVInAppBrowser.o
      -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[CDVInAppBrowser openInSystem:] in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAPlugin in GAPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVClipboard in CDVClipboard.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVInAppBrowser in CDVInAppBrowser.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GAPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVClipboard.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVConnection.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVUserAgentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVWebViewDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAPlugin in GAPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVClipboard in CDVClipboard.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVInAppBrowser in CDVInAppBrowser.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I spent few hours already to figure out what is going on, but it seems to be out of my reach. I did followed many suggestions found on web, but  with no result. I tried to add "missing" frameworks from within Build Phases section, I played with "Build Active Architectures Only", I tried to add this i386 architecture to list of valid architectures for both Target and Project.
All these to no effect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What version of cordova is your project using?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon - we run on 3.6.3-0.2.13 build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that, I had a missing architecture (i386) for **Cordova** build of my application. My "cordova.a file was ignored" (as per my warning), because in fact I've lost i386 architecture setting after Xcode upgrade. To resolve this I needed to add this architecture by clicking **Cordova.xcodeproj** file. Then I get to **Cordova** (not Project) build settings where I had to add my missing architecture for both Target and Project part of **Cordova Build**.

I wasn't even aware of this section exists. So I tried many times to adjust architectures on my Project itself (by clicking on the project name in Navigator and accessing build settings tab), but to fix my issue, I just had to do this same by clicking Cordova.xcodeproj file instead.

This [link](https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/) helped me out, so you might want to follow too.